# AdapterView is a raw type. References to generic type AdapterView<T> should be parameterized

Tags: java, android, class, apk

my code showing this error...AdapterView is a raw type. References to generic type AdapterView should be parameterized for the AdapterView, what should i do?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterview, View view, int i, long l) //*AdapterView is a raw type. References to generic type AdapterView<T> should be parameterized 
{
    ((ImageView)b.findViewById(0x7f090000)).setImageResource(a.getResources().obtainTypedArray(0x7f050000).getResourceId(i, -1));
    ((Button)b.findViewById(0x7f090002)).setOnClickListener(new c(this, b));
    ((Button)b.findViewById(0x7f090003)).setOnClickListener(new d(this, i));
    String s = a.getIntent().getAction();
    if ("android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT".equals(s) || "android.intent.action.PICK".equals(s))
    {
        ((Button)b.findViewById(0x7f090004)).setOnClickListener(new e(this, i, b));
    }
    b.show();
}
```

Comment: That's not an error. That should be a warning. And I guess the message has helped you enough.

Answer (score 4):

This is because this `AdapterView` is probably parametrized, which means that in its implementation the type is not forced, for example, to `String` or whatever else, but it's defined by the user.

So basically what the warning (not error) is telling you that instead of `AdapterView adapterview` you have to set it to `AdapterView<YourType> adapterview` (so you'd need to put here the type you've defined the `AdapterView` in the declaration.

Comment: so what i have to put in there <?> . ?

Comment: Exactly, you've to put `AdapterView<?> adapterview`.

Comment: ohh yeah it worked...
awesome feel when you accidently give a solutions to your own problem xD